# jquery datalist show labels

Tags: html, datalist

How to show the data list labels but submit the actual value to the database?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="reg_input">Parent Name</label>

    <input list="parentName" name="parentsName" id="parentsName" class="form-control">

    <datalist style="color: #FFF" id="parentName">
        <?php
        $pa="select * from parents";
        $par=mysql_query($pa);
        while ($childrens=mysql_fetch_array($par)) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $childrens['UserName'];?>" data-value="<?php echo $childrens['UserID'] ?>"></option>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </datalist>                            
</div>
```